# Disable rails routing logs in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I have a application which receives large number of requests, and to reduce log file size I want to remove some logs.

One of the logs that I am trying to remove is :

```
I, [2015-09-09T19:01:01.372374 #10897]  INFO -- : Processing by Api::V1::MyAPIController#show as JSON
```

Basically this log shows to which controller actions the request is getting routed to. I want to remove this log. Is it possible to remove this specific log or change it's log level to debug. Please provide a way to remove this log, as this log by itself provides little information but is taking up considerable disk space.

Thanks for help,

Comment: Don't you consider log rotation possibility?

Comment: Hi,
I already have log rotation set up and logs are being archived. But to further improve system performance I want to remove this logs. As the API calls by themselves are light-weight but these logs are taking up much space.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to cut output is to change `log_level`. In your `config/environments/production.rb` file locate line:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

and change `debug` to `info`, `warn`, `error`, or `fatal`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

**Update** To silence *only* routing logs, we can use [`silencer` gem](https://github.com/stve/silencer).

In **production.rb**

```
require 'silencer/logger'
config.middleware.swap Rails::Rack::Logger, Silencer::Logger, :silence => [%r{^/}]
```

This will silence all routing logs by replacing `Rails::Rack::Logger` with silencer on all routes.

More info on `silencer` configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/stve/silencer).

Comment: log-level of the particular log that I want to remove is INFO. If I change config.log_level to :error or higher, it will remove all the INFO logs. But I only want to remove that particular log line, not all INFO logs.

Comment: Hi dimakura@,
though I don't understand how silencer works, I added it to production.rb in my rails applications. But I still see those logs. This does not seem to be working.

Comment: I checked it and it works fine for me. Absolute silence :)

Comment: My bad, I changed wrong environment file. This has removed the "Processing by Controller#action" log, but it also has removed some other logs e.g. rails Parameters log which logs input parameters, and "Completed 200 OK" kindof logs. Can I remove only that particular log which I asked in Ques.